# How can I extract a string using C# Substring

Tags: c#

I want to extract the browser name and Operating system in differant strings from 
this string. How can I use substring to extract them from

```
{  Browser/leavethis (Operating System) Leavethis/Leavethis (Leavethis, Leavethis) Leavethis/Leavethis/Leavethis }
```

Comment: Do you know the exact length? If not: either use regular expressions or a combination of IndexOf/Substring

Comment: So, Browser is the trimmed stuff between (first) "{" and first "/" and Operating System ist stuff between first "(" and first ")"? Well, that should give you an idea on what to do.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the `Leavethis` - is that meant to be left in the string? What about the braces, slahes and brackets?

Comment: http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/aOqmXQM_460s_v2.jpg when I read this type of 'question' I see this

Comment: I don't know the exact lenght of string but it is of same symbol containing. leave this is the part of string which should be leave while extrcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting the useragent, you should use the properties already supplied the Asp.net Framework to detect the browser/os.

Use this

1. to get the browser name `Request.Browser.Browser` and browser version `Request.Browser.MajorVersion`
2. to get the Os name `Request.Browser.Platform` and os version Request.UserAgent

Comment: I solve this by making following methods in code file and accessing them in html     public String Browser(string bro)
    {
        int end = bro.IndexOf('(');
        string b = bro;
        if (end != -1)
        {
            b = bro.Substring(0, end);
        }
        return b;
    }
    public string Os(string os)
    {
        int end = os.IndexOf(')');
        int start = os.IndexOf('(') + 1;
        int tot = end - start;
        string b = os;
        if (end != -1)
        {
            b = os.Substring(start, tot);
        }
        return b;

Answer (score 0):

A regex such as the following should work, but I suspect @bastos.sergio's answer is the correct way to get what you need.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"{\s+(?<Browser>\w+)/[^(]+\((?<OperatingSystem>[^)]+).+");
string browser;
string OS;

var match = r.Match(s);

if (match.Success)
{
    browser = match.Groups["Browser"].Value;
    OS = match.Groups["OperatingSystem"].Value;
}
```